# Can´t execute file after writing it to the disk

Tags: c#, wpf, networking, tcp, stream

I have a few files I transfer over TCP. However when I then try to execute them I get an windows screen pop up, saying I should contact the developer to get an appropriate version for my pc. The files should be transferred correctly so I am wondering where the problem lays.

Server OS: Windows Server 2016

My PC OS: Windows 10

**Server code**

```
private void SendLauncherFiles(NetworkStream stream)
    {
        TCPManager manager = new TCPManager();
        Console.WriteLine("Sending Launcher files");

        string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        path += "LauncherFiles\\";

        string[] extensions = { "LegitAimLauncher.exe", "Bleak.dll", "Jupiter.dll", "PeNet.Asn1.dll", "PeNet.dll" };

        for(int i = 0; i < extensions.Length; i++)
        {
            path += extensions[i];
            byte[] bFileData = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            string newPath = path.Replace(extensions[i], "");
            path = newPath;

            manager.SendInt(bFileData.Length, stream);
            stream.Write(bFileData, 0, bFileData.Length);
        }

    }
```

**Client Code**

```
private void ReceiveFiles(NetworkStream stream)
    {
        TCPManager manager = new TCPManager();

        string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        path += "LauncherFiles\\";

        string[] extensions = { "LegitAimLauncher.exe", "Bleak.dll", "Jupiter.dll", "PeNet.Asn1.dll", "PeNet.dll" };

        for(int i = 0; i < extensions.Length; i++)
        {
            path += extensions[i];
            int length = manager.GetInt(stream);

            byte[] bFileData = new byte[length];
            stream.Read(bFileData, 0, bFileData.Length);

            File.WriteAllBytes(path, bFileData);

            string newPath = path.Replace(extensions[i], "");
            path = newPath;
        }
    }
```

**TCPManager**

```
public void SendInt(int data, NetworkStream stream)
    {
        byte[] bData = BitConverter.GetBytes(data);

        stream.Write(bData, 0, bData.Length);
    }
public int GetInt(NetworkStream stream)
    {
        byte[] bData = new byte[sizeof(int)];
        stream.Read(bData, 0, bData.Length);
        int Data = BitConverter.ToInt32(bData, 0);

        return Data;
    }
```

EDIT: Forgot to check for file size. All the files have a size of zero bytes so there must be an error somewhere while sending.

Comment: It could be one of two problems: the files are not being sent properly or a prerequisite for the program is missing on the client machine. To see if the file is getting there properly, you can use PowerShell's [Get-FileHash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash) on the files on the server and on the client and see if they match (you need at least PowerShell v4 for that).

Comment: To see if a prerequisite is missing, then copy the files by some other method and try to run it and see if you get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from things like checking the correct runtime versions are installed on the target system and the like...

Could it be that when you are not receiving the entire file content in a single `Read` operation?

You can (and should) ensure that you read all the data using something like:

(Untested...)

```
var offset = 0;
while (offset < length)
{
    var read = stream.Read(buffer, offset, length - offset);
    if (read == 0) {
        //Socket disconnected
        break;
    }
    offset += read;
}
```

You can (and should) also do a similar thing with the `Write` call to ensure that all data has been written... it doesn't happen often, but it *does* happen - for various reasons that are not for this thread :) (Murphy's Law and all that!)